# Не находит константну (в основном на IOS)

Tags: javascript, константа

#### Описание

В проекте, при переходе на одну из страниц, сайт должен проверять присутствуют данные в `localStorage`? Если да то они должны быть присвоены константу `sheet` и обработаны. Основная структура кода выглядит так:

```js
if (archivePreview.data) {
    const sheet = archivePreview.data;
    ...
    function search(pattern) {
        ...
        for (const pole of sheet) {
```

...где `archivePreview` экземпляр специального класса который получает данные из `localStorage`. Ошибка...

> Can't find variable **sheet**

...выскакивает в `for (const pole of sheet) {` (в основном на IOS, всего раз попался конфликтующий Android) и совершенно нет понятий почему.

#### Дополнение

Собственно вот [исходники](https://github.com/eccs0103/Cheatsheet/tree/2ae0c81656ee1a7256c47e7441c1e65e6c6d21f3). Ошибка возникает, если импортировать ссылку...

> пример ссылки: https://github.com/eccs0103/Cheatsheet/blob/2ae0c81656ee1a7256c47e7441c1e65e6c6d21f3/scripts/database/ecology-18-12-2022.json

...базы данных в сайт, через кнопку Import и нажать по появившийся кнопке.

#### Вопрос

Почему возникает такая ошибка?
Почему в основном на устройствах с IOS?
Какие тонкие моменты есть на IOS к чему следовало бы наблюдать чтобы дальше не столкнутся с такими ошибками?

#### Дополнительно

В основная проверка была на версии IOS 16.0.2 и соответственно у Safari та же версия.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141553/discussion-on-question-by-eccs0103-------ios).

Answer (score 0):

Речь идёт о поддержке стандарта **JS** - **[ES6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp)**, который даёт возможность использовать `let`, `const` и ещё кучу крутых штук, что дал нам этот стандарт.

**Как же быть?**

Ответа два:

1. Забить на **Safari**.

   Начать забастовку, как делали единицы сайтов, которые при в ходе с **IE** выдавали надпись "Ваш браузер устарел, установите ...", только сейчас делать такое для **Safari**, может когда-нибудь гиганты маркетинга из **IOS** подумают не о деньгах, а о пользователях\разработчиках и обновят браузер или сделают как "микро-мягкие", перейдут на движок **[Chromium](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium)**.
2. Поддерживать **Safari**.

   Писать по стандарту **ES5**, если требуется **ES6** - использовать [полифилы](https://learn.javascript.ru/polyfills), перебирать кучу сайтов с баг-фиксами по **Safari**.
   Можно, кстати, не писать под стандарт ниже, а использовать транскриптеры, например **[Babel.js](https://babeljs.io)**.
   Вот например [пример вашего кода](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=JYMwBAFAhgTgxgC2ANwKYAUaucVB3AOgBMoAXKASjAG8AoMBsOAewDsBnUsdhVVLgLxhYiFBiw58xMlADc9RgHpFYAmoUMQAV1ZxSwNt1QiEEAA5lSqGKyp1GDsMtXrHjEMxiQWHLmeYANqhgzOA8fKR2Gm5g0Q4AvtGJ8UA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=true&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.20.6&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D), который я "перегнал" под **ES5**.

Comment: Проблема была в `const`. Заменил все `const`-ы в `var` и заработало.

Comment: Не распространяйте дезинформацию и проверяйте факты при написании ответов! Safari [поддерживает let/const](https://caniuse.com/const) уже больше пяти лет, а проблема автора скорее всего в том, что он просто использовал слишком старую версию iOS

Comment: Проверил Safari 15 — ошибка таки есть, но проблема явно не в поддержке let/const как таковой, а в каких-то тонкостях обработки блочной области видимости

Comment: @andreymal, до каких-то версий у `const` не было блочной видимости

Comment: @Grundy ну не в Safari 15 же блин ¯\\(°_o)/¯